# Circular import issue in python. How to resolve it?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

Helloooo!

Usually, circular import means an structure problem within the code, but I can't see any other way to fix this. 
This is my current case:

I have two classes: `Project` and `Preset`

`Project` has a method that will generate a `Preset`, something like:

```py
from preset import Preset

class Project():

    def __init__(self, project):
        self._project_name = project

    def get_preset(self, preset_name):
        return Preset(preset_name, self._project_name)
```

Then, I have the `Preset` class, which also needs a `Project` name to get initialised. Something like:

```py
from project import Project

class Preset():

    def __init__(self, preset_name, project_name):
        self._project = Project(project_name)
```

Generally speaking, I will always create the `Presets` through the `Project` class with the `get_preset` method, but I want to also give the possibility to create a `Preset` directly without having to create a `Project` first.

Any ideas to get rid of this circular recursion?

Thanks!!

Comment: Move the `get_preset` from `Project` to `Preset` and call `Preset.get_preset(preset_name)` inside  `Project.get_preset`?

Comment: I've updated the code example, because it was wrong. `Preset` initialisation needs the preset_name and the project_name which the preset belongs to, so I cannot address it like this :(
Thanks!!!

Comment: It seems bad that when you access your project's preset, it creates a preset with a *new* Project inside of it rather than referencing the actual project that it's associated with.  But leaving that aside, circular references are still bad.  What does `Preset` need from `Project`, and what does `Project` need from `Preset`?  If the answer to either of those is "nothing", you have no logical dependency, so you should remove the import dependency.  Otherwise, figure out the way to change one of those answers.  :)

Comment: I've finished passing the `Project` object into the `Preset` constructor. Anyway, I'm still getting circular dependencies, due to the type hints. I fixed with: `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: import Preset`. I don't like it at all, but... Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You could move the first import into the `get_preset` function.

Comment: Yep... that could work, but... is it really pythonic?

Comment: If you're committed to having cyclic dependencies in your project, you're going to have to live with ugly code to make them work.  It's better to remove the cycles if possible though!  :)